# CocoaPods lib - ld: warning: directory not found for option

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I have added SSKeychain to my pods file and install it again

Now I get an error:
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/.../Debug-iphonesimulator/SSKeychain

If I open this dir, I see only libPods-PureSight.a, but not any SSKeychain folder

frustrating...